# Struts2 Tiles configuration issue

Tags: struts2

I am configuring tiles in struts2.

I have added all the needed jars.`Struts-tiles-plugin`,`tiles-api`,`tiles-compat`,`tiles-jsp`,`tiles-core`,`tiles-servlet`,`commons-beanutils`,`commons-digester` etc..

But I am getting this error.
My complete stack trace is

```
Apr 25, 2012 9:55:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.UrlSet.<init>(Lcom/opensymphony/xwork2/util/finder/ClassLoaderInterface;Ljava/util/Set;)V
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildUrlSet(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:380)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.findActions(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:352)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildActionConfigs(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:317)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.ClasspathPackageProvider.loadPackages(ClasspathPackageProvider.java:53)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:200)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:418)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3693)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4340)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:920)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:883)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1138)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:566)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Apr 25, 2012 9:55:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Apr 25, 2012 9:55:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/UBITECWeb] startup failed due to previous errors
```

How to resolve this problem
Please anyone solve this ...

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Add xwork-core jar file also. That has the UrlSet class.

Comment: i have added  xwork-core,Xwork jars..even am getting the same error..i am not at all understanding..can u please suggest something..i am new to struts2..and have little bit experience only with struts1.x

Comment: You could be using an incorrect version of xwork-core. How did you get all the jar files to being with? I would suggest that you get from Struts2 website. Use the blank project and build on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

Where you add the .jars in :

1. right button > Properties > Java Build Path > and then and jar or other opcion.
2. inside the project explorer in the folder WEB-INF > lib.

   If your answer is the 2, try to use also the first option. I have the .jars in both places and not have problemes.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

It is due to mismatch is jar files, Use maven to download all the necessary jars, It will do all. All you have to do is specify the struts dependencies. Take some samples projects and try.

[ViralPatel site](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/struts-2-tiles-plugin-tutorial-with-example-in-eclipse/) is having the example application with the necessary libraries specified. Refer it.